# SQL Server 2008 Web Edition & CRM/LOB limitation - what does this mean?

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

We are reconsidering using SQL Server 2008 Web Edition, but are wondering exactly what Microsoft means by not being able to host LOB applications "such as CRM".

We provide our clients with web applications for performing financial transactions online.  We also have internal users that utilize these same applications.  Some features are only available to clients, and a few features are only available to internal users.  Almost all features are exclusively accessed via the web.

Would this be considered a LOB application?  The person I spoke with at Microsoft was very circumspect.  I'd hate to spend $$$ licensing an app and find out we can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is definitely the case of a web application. MS is pretty explicitely here. Anything HTTP based internet facing is a web application.

The Web-limitation is basically so you do not end up usin the very cheap web licenses to host backend stuff that is not exposed to the internet at all.

You would also not be allowed to host your own internal applications there. Naturally all customer / internet facing sides also have an internal only area for maintenance / administration.